Is there a manual method in snowflake to replicate a cache miss scenario?
I would like to write error handling logic around cache misses in snowflake and am looking for a convenient method of replicating that situation.
Specifically I'd like to replicate a scenario where the user is running post-processing on a query that was ran weeks ago, and is no longer available (causing their query to error in a cache miss).
Is there an option for a snowflake admin to delete specific query id's from the cache, or is this a generally unsupported option?
Without it, it looks like I'll need to wait out the time it takes for cache results to expire before I have any data on what the error results would look like.
I've gone through much of the general documentation, and found resources on the RESULT SCAN method, but can't find any solid information on what sort of errors will be returned on cache misses (or if there is any ability to purge individual queries from the cache).

Hi - why can’t you use any query id for a query that ran more than 24 hours ago to simulate the query cache having expired?

I agree that's definitely an option, I was just hoping for something that's more on demand, and easy to replicate.

Hi - I’m not sure how/why you don’t consider this to be on demand or easy to replicate? Just query for any “older than 24 hours” query id and feed it into your process

I was working in an environment where I didn't have access to any old queries that had been evicted from the cache. I'm also curious to better understand what capabilities snowflake offers. I agree that in general most snowflake clients aren't particularly bothered by this scenario, and that this is a niche case, and probably not on snowflakes radar to support.

Although I can't supply a valid way to trigger this error message instantaneously, I can give other readers a snapshot of the current response Snowflake returns in this scenario after I waited the 24 hours for the cache to expire. The error message reads: Result for query "{queryId}" has expired
Some of the relevant data in the response includes:
code: 000710
name: OperationFailedError
sqlState: 02000

Unfortunately although Snowflake provides guidance on how to handle query responses, they don't appear to offer a comprehensive list of error messages and their meaning.
